# Unselect JTable row when row index < 0

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, mouselistener

My question is really simple, I just don't know how to query this on google.

What I want is just to print the selected row index when I click a row on a `JTable`.

[image: sample]

The problem is if I click a valid row index
(which is `index >= 0 && index < rowCount`) and then I click outside of the valid rows on lower part of the table which has no rows (obviously it is now `index < 0`) the row index that is printed is still the last valid row index that I clicked.
What I want for this is to print the `"No row selected"` and clears the row selection when I clicked on the lower blank part of the table which has no rows.

[image]

(I am already clicking outside of the rows here on the lower blank part of the table)

Here is my codes:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
        if(rowIndex < 0) {
            System.out.println("No row selected");
            table.clearSelection();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Row " + rowIndex + " selected");
        }
    }
});
```

The only time that this simple program works the way I want it to do is when I set the `setFillsViewportHeight` to `false` or just omit it since it is `false` by default.

So how can I do this while the `table.setFillsViewportHeight` is set to `true`?

Comment: probably you would need to use [List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html), not idea about your setting with [JTable.setSelectionMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), [maybe more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+ListSelectionListener)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint())` to get the clicked row. It will return `-1` if the selection is not valid (When you click below the table):

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //Updated to use rowAtPoint
    int rowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());

    //Existing code
    if(rowIndex < 0) {
        System.out.println("No row selected");
        table.clearSelection();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Row " + rowIndex + " selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: I "might" consider looking at the selected row index from the table in the `else` condition, just be sure, but I'd have to spend some time looking at the event notification workflow to be 100%, otherwise, the basic idea is correct ✅